# How do I rejuvenate my Date Palm Tree?

Tags: trees, plant-health, tree-care

I've had this date palm tree for a little over a year now and the leaves have started to turn yellow with some of the bottom leaves dying out, is there any way to rejuvenate the plant, should I cut away the dead leaves at the bottom? Also, am I ok keeping it in a patio plant pot, as I'd rather not plant in the ground as I don't really have space in the garden?

[image: date palm tree]

[image: leaves at bottom]

Comment: What part of the world are you in? And how long has the palm been in its current pot?

Comment: I live in west London UK, it's only been in that pot for a few weeks, I transferred it from an even smaller pot that wasn't draining water properly. I re potted it with compost and bonemeal, should the pot be larger.?

Comment: Funny,  so do I...

Answer (score 1):

By the look of the moss and lichen surrounding the base of the plant, which isn't present towards the outer edges, that's what I thought might have happened - it was in a smaller pot over winter, presumably.

Phoenix canariensis (which is what this plant is) isn't technically hardy outdoors in the UK - with mild winters, a sheltered position, a warmer part of the country and some winter protection, they may live outdoors for a while, but they generally look like yours does at the end of it, with browning or dead leaves. What I can't tell from the photos is whether there's been any new growth this year, from the centre at the top, its not visible in the photos if there is new growth - if the central growth point is dead, then your palm will die, I'm afraid.

If there is growth, then trim off the lower, damaged leaves, the two which are completely dead and brown, but leave the rest in place for the time being, though you can trim off the dead parts on the others near the top. Pull off the moss and lichen that's visible at the base - you may need to top up with a little compost to keep the roots covered afterwards.

With regard to pot size, so long as the pot its now in had sufficient room for there to be a good inch of extra potting compost all round the rootball, including beneath, it doesn't yet need a new pot - but will next year in spring, if it survives. I'm assuming there is a drainage hole in the base of your pot, and that it's not blocked, enabling water to drain away freely.

If the plant dies and you would still like a potted palm, the hardy one here is Trachycarpus fortunei.

Comment: Fantastic help, really appreciate your assistance, I'll post back here and let you know how I get on :)